# onClickListener parameter casted to a textview

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am trying to make the onClickListener parameter, for example:

```
public void onClick(View v){}
```

**v**, to be casted to a TextView and set the text to this **x** textView, but I cannot specify the textView because I want it to be a different one each time the onClick is triggered. Basically I want to setText for the parameter:

```
(TextView) v.setText("");
```

And the problem is that the setText() method cannot be used this way, so is there any way I can do this? Sorry if I did not explain well and thanks in forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
((TextView) v).setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your casting is wrong, If that view is `TextView`, you should cast TextView like `((TextView) v)` and then you can do any operation.

Ex:  `((TextView) v).setText("");`